# Script to automate TempDB free space check on SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-scripts

Can anyone advice me how to write a script to automate `TempDB` free space check on SQL Server instances?

At the moment I connect to all instances individually and run the script

```
use tempdb
exec sp_spaceused
```

I have to repeat this for 10 other instances, which is very time consuming. I am a beginner and not very familiar with scripting. I would really appreciate if anyone could advice me on how to set up script to do this automatically so I can simply open a file to check the free space for the day for all instances.

Comment: For MS SQL Server or?

Answer (score 0):

[Using Registered Servers to Manage Servers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173574(v=sql.105).aspx)